# Should I break circular dependencies between C++ module fragments using forward declarations?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

Can C++ modules in Visual Studio 2022 handle forward declarations?

The following code has a circular dependency that I want to break using a forward declaration, but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize that it refers to the same type as the full class declaration, so it doesn't compile. Am I doing something wrong?

main.cpp

```
import A;

int main()
{
    CB cb;
    CC cc;
    cc.MyFunc3(cb);
    return 0;
}
```

A.ixx

```
export module A;

export import :B;
export import :C;
```

A-B.ixx

```
export module A:B;

class CC;

export class CB {
public:
    void MyFunc(const CC& cc) const;
};
```

A-B.cpp

```
module A;
import :B;

import std;
import :C;

void CB::MyFunc(const CC& cc)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World B" << std::endl;
}
```

A-C.ixx

```
export module A:C;

class CB;

export class CC {
public:
    void MyFunc1(const CB& cb) const;
};
```

A-C.cpp

```
module A;
import :C;

import std;
import :B;

void CC::MyFunc1(const CB& cb)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World B" << std::endl;
    cb.MyFunc(*this);
}
```

This is the error:

```
1>C:\Users\peterB\repositories\hobby projecten\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\A-C.cpp(7,10): error C2511: 'void CC::MyFunc1(const CB &)': overloaded member function not found in 'CC'
1>C:\Users\peterB\repositories\hobby projecten\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\A-C.ixx(5,14):
1>see declaration of 'CC'
1>C:\Users\peterB\repositories\hobby projecten\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\A-C.cpp(10,5): error C2027: use of undefined type 'CB'
1>C:\Users\peterB\repositories\hobby projecten\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\A-C.ixx(3,7):
1>see declaration of 'CB'
1>C:\Users\peterB\repositories\hobby projecten\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\Hexanaut-AI\A-C.cpp(10,16): error C2671: 'CC::MyFunc1': static member functions do not have 'this' pointers
```

Relevant compiler options:

```
/std:c++latest /experimental:module
```

With 'Build ISO C++23 standard library modules' turned on.

Comment: Why you think you need forward declaration at all? Why not just import module `A:C`? When headers are used forward declarations are used to reduce includes from header file (so in case of changes in single header cascade of recopies is reduced), here you do not have headers so no need to use forward declaration.

Comment: @MarekR maybe I should've framed my question differently. I'm using forward declarations to break circular dependencies between module (fragments). What's the go to strategy to do this?

Comment: Any circular dependency (not only in a code) is indication of bad code design. Such cycle means both classes can't be shipped without other, so there is no reason to keep them in separate module r even separate translation unit.

Comment: Circular dependencies are very normal and common place. Documentation I've found says to put those into separate module fragments (which means in the same module but still in different files).
An example is when a class calls a function on one of its members and gives itself to the function as a parameter. Then both class declarations need to refer to each other.

Comment: @Jupiter: "*I'm using forward declarations to break circular dependencies between module (fragments).*" I don't see the circular dependency here. `A:C` can import `A:B`.

Comment: @Jupiter: Also, you have multiple module partition units with the same name. This is not allowed. `A-C.cpp` and `A-C.ixx` both declare the partition `A:C`. You can't do that. `A-C.cpp` should be a non-partition unit.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've changed the question to include a circular dependency for clarity.

I followed Microsofts tutorial to reach the file structure above. This includes a naming convention for files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170

The .cpp files are so called module implementation unit. The difference is that they leave out the 'export' key word at the 'module <mod-name>;' line at the top.

Comment: @Jupiter: I don't care what Microsoft's tutorial says. [The *standard* says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/module#unit-3) this: "A named module shall not contain multiple module partitions with the same module-partition." If they don't give an error for this, then they've implemented the standard incorrectly. These should be non-partition implementation units. They shouldn't have partition names.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've changed the code. Is it correct now? There is still an error. Can you show in an answer how you would structure the code?

Comment: @Jupiter take a look on [Uncle Bob talk about SOLID principles](https://youtu.be/zHiWqnTWsn4). Dependency cycles are mention there. Yes circular dependence are very common (since bad code is very common), I have an example where it is ok: list and list node. But any cycle which speeds beyond single translation unit are just bad code design (see Uncle Bob lecture). Like I wrote you can't separate code (use just piece of it in different context) which is part of cycle.

Comment: @MarekR I'm actually creating a game. I have a game state. It contains players. But my players need a game state in order to make decisions. That's a cycle. Is that design really so unreasonable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more consistent about your `export` declarations. This *includes* forward declarations. `CC` and `CB` are both supposed to be `export`ed. This means that the forward declarations of them should *also* be `exported`.

One way to avoid excess repetition is to have a module interface partition for such declarations that all other partitions import:

```
//A-fwd.ixx
export module A:fwd;

export class CB;
export class CC;

//A-B.ixx
export module A:B;

export import :fwd;

export class CB {...};
```

The `export` in `A-B` is not necessary, but it's good as a reminder. `A-C.ixx` should also import `:fwd`.

Note that my reading of the standard is that it *should* have given a compile error when compiling the module `A`. That file imports `A:B`, which declares `CC` as non-exported. When it imports `A:C` that declares it exported, that should have triggered [[module.interface]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/module.interface#6):

> A redeclaration of an entity X is implicitly exported if X was introduced by an exported declaration; otherwise it shall not be exported.

That "shall not be exported" translates to "ill-formed if the entity is redeclared as exported". But VC++ didn't do that apparently.

It does give an error *eventually*, but only when you try to use it. See, it seems to be translating your code such that there are two types named `CB`: the exported one and the non-exported one. The object `cb` is of the exported type, but the type used by `CC::MyFunc3` is the non-exported one. Since they are two different types, and no conversion operator is defined, you get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the export to the forward declarations but the error persisted. I have also put them in a A-fwd partition as suggested, and then also imported that in the implementation units but it didn't help. I'm still getting `A-C.cpp(8,10): error C2511: 'void CC::MyFunc1(const CB &)': overloaded member function not found in 'CC'`

Comment: Actually, after playing a bit more, I also discovered that the function definitions were missing the trailing const. Adding that fixed all error. So in the end, your answer was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Two key things were missing: exporting the forward declaration but also importing them into the module implementation units.
I got it working as well with module implementation units for the partitions. Here is my full solution:

main.cpp

```
import A;

int main()
{
    CB cb;
    CC cc;
    cc.MyFunc3(cb);
    return 0;
}
```

A-fwddecl.ixx

```
export module A:fwddecl;

export class CB;
export class CC;
```

A.ixx

```
export module A;

export import :B;
export import :C;
```

A-B.ixx

```
export module A:B;

import :fwddecl;

export class CB {
public:
    void MyFunc(const CC& cc) const;
};
```

A-B.cpp

```
module A:B;
import :B;

import std;
import :C;

void CB::MyFunc(const CC& cc) const
{
    std::cout << "Hello World B" << std::endl;
}
```

A-C.ixx

```
export module A:C;

import :fwddecl;

export class CC {
public:
    void MyFunc1(const CB& cb) const;
};
```

A-C.cpp

```
module A:C;
import :C;

import std;
import :B;

void CC::MyFunc1(const CB& cb) const
{
    std::cout << "Hello World C" << std::endl;
    cb.MyFunc(*this);
}
```

If a partition ever needs something which is declared in the A module itself, just `import A;` in the module implementation unit of the partition.